# How to ensure that a List in C# always has a specific element?

Tags: c#, list, element

I have a class named GameObject that has a dynamic List of Components. Those components can be removed and added at any time. A Component could possibly be a Texture, Sound or Transition etc. What's the best way to ensure that this list always has one Transition component? Only one component of each type is allowed.

I have two posibble solutions in my mind. Which one of these is the best? And *are there any better* solutions to this problem?

**Approach 1:**

```
class GameObject {
    private List<Component> components;

    public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component {
        // search the requested component and return it
        foreach(Component comp in components) {
            if(comp is T) return (T)comp;
        }
        // return null or throw exception when not found
        return null;
    }

    public void RemoveComponent<T>() where T : Component {
        if(typeof(T) != typeof(Transition)) {
            // only remove the componenent if it's not a Transition component
            Component tmp;
            foreach(Component comp in components) {
                if(comp is T) tmp = comp;
                break;
            }
            components.Remove(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
class GameObject {
    // separate variable for the transition component
    private Transition transition;
    private List<Component> components;

    public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component {
        // if a transition is requestet just return it
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(Transition)) {
            return transition;
        }
        // else: search the requested component in the list
        foreach(Component comp in components) {
            if(comp is T) return (T)comp;
        }
        // return null or throw exception when not found
        return null;
    }

    public void RemoveComponent<T>() where T : Component {
        if(typeof(T) != typeof(Transition)) {
            // only remove the componenent if it's not a Transition component
            Component tmp;
            foreach(Component comp in components) {
                if(comp is T) tmp = comp;
                break;
            }
            components.Remove(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why store the Transition in the list then? Just move it to an own dedicated variable and there is no worrying.

Comment: Nice solutions! I would totally use the first one! ps: You could also use a boolean whenever the transition is removed or inserted! :D

Comment: Can you have repeated type objects in you list? For example two Transitions, two textures or just only one ? If you can't repeat type elements I would use a Dictorionary<Type, object> instead of a List, it will be faster

Comment: I would say that the second approach is better because it directly encodes into the type that there is at least one `Transition`. However be careful with `if(typeof(T) != typeof(Transition))`, because this will be `true` for subtypes of `Transition` where I think you might want it to be `false`.

Comment: The list should contain only one component of each type.

Comment: Doesn't the second version prevent the removal of *any* Transitions? I thought the requirement was to ensure the presence of at least *one* transition, so if the list contained n>1, I could remove (n-1) of them. That implies tracking the first Transition added to the list, and ensuring it doesn't get removed.

Comment: @Mandalore as I said use a Dictionary it will be faster, and the code will be smaller, without need to use foreach.

Comment: @Mandalore I would add that to your problem statement, then. That's a fairly important requirement. I thought the number of each type of Component was not limited.

Comment: Instead of a dictionary a simple boolean? there's or there's not!

Comment: Does this compile? I think GetComponent is missing a blanket `return default(T)` statement at the end.

Comment: It's working for me because I throw a exception after the `foreach`. Alternatively you could use `return null`.
@Jared Moore: Is there a better way to do the type check `if(typeof(T) != typeof(Transition))`?

Comment: I think what you want is `if (!typeof(Transition).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))`. Hopefully all of these typeof's won't impact your performance too much, I think reflection can be slow in some scenarios (not sure if this will be or not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to create what is known as an entity component model. I suggest analyzing some engines which use that model, such as the 
[Paradox Game Engine](https://github.com/SiliconStudio/paradox).

The [Entity](https://github.com/SiliconStudio/paradox/blob/f5c45f5855842d0fe0942032dc08230ce9bb034d/sources/engine/SiliconStudio.Paradox.Engine/Engine/Entity.cs) (GameObject) and [PropertyContainer](https://github.com/SiliconStudio/paradox/blob/f5c45f5855842d0fe0942032dc08230ce9bb034d/sources/common/core/SiliconStudio.Core/PropertyContainer.cs) (component collection) should be of particular interest for you.

It's probably a good idea to keep the transition component both as a separate field and also store it in the components list. Since it's something that is guaranteed to be part of each game object, you could provide a separate getter property for direct access to this component to bypass any lookup cost.

Since you seem to allow only one component per type, it would be efficient to store the components in a `Dictionary<Type, Component>`. That would provide really quick lookups in comparison to iterating over the the components and doing type comparisons.

A slightly modified version of your 2nd approach:

```
class GameObject
{        
    private readonly Transition transition = new Transition();
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Component> components = new Dictionary<Type, Component>();        

    public GameObject()
    {
        AddComponent(transition);
    }

    public Transition Transition { get { return transition; } }

    public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {
        Component component;
        if (components.TryGetValue(typeof (T), out component))
        {
            return (T) component;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void AddComponent<T>(T component) where T : Component
    {
        Type type = typeof (T);
        if (!components.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            components.Add(type, component);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {                        
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(Transition))
        {
            components.Remove(typeof (T));                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It comes late but thank you. :) Your solution helped me.